# Fastening the data extraction

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I am having more than 1 million rows of data in SQL database. I want to write that whole data to TSV file. I am using the below code to fetch top 100000 rows. It takes nearly 20 minutes to fetch and write it to TSV file. Any other method to fasten this process?

```
 cursor.execute("select top(100000) from dbo.StoreLocations_Repo_V10")       
 store_details = cursor.fetchall()
 store_details_list = [list(elem) for elem in store_details] 
 df = pd.DataFrame(store_details_list)          

 with open('result.tsv', 'w', encoding='UTF-8') as f:
    df.to_csv(f, header=False, sep='\t')
```

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Did you try using https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_sql.html ?

Comment: given `top` and `dbo.` usage, I would suspect SQL Server is being used here.

Comment: Yes. I am using SQL server.

Comment: Have you profiled your code.  Which step is taking the time?  Have you determined any factors influencing the step taking the longest?  Or would you like us to guess if you have network issues, a slow database, a slow hard drive, maybe even writing to a network drive?

Comment: I guess 2nd line of my code(i.e) cursor.fetchall() is taking more time. Since it fetch all the 100000 rows from DB and put it a list. In my point of view if there is any way to split the fetching method that is fetching 10000 rows first and repeat the same until 100000. May be it will reduce the time right?

Comment: You are tranferring the complete table, then you perform an extra pass (in your frontend) to select the wanted elements. Instead, you could do the selection in SQL.

Comment: I am in need of 55 columns from the target table and I replaced the above select query corresponding to it. Even then it take more time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
import pyodbc

import pandas as pd

connection = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};'
                            'Server=YourServer;'
                            'Database=YourDB;'
                            'Trusted_Connection=yes;')

data = "select top(100000) from dbo.StoreLocations_Repo_V10"

df = pd.read_sql(data, connection)

df.to_csv('result.tsv', header=False, sep='\t')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's working perfectly. Now it take only 5 min to fetch 100000 rows.

Comment: @Saranya I'm glad it helped :)